# How to Convert VS2003 proj to VS2005 proj

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2005

Hi I have test project which I need to convert from VS2003 to VS2005 and I am afraid I got lot of errors and warnings.

The error mostly appeared is ** error C2220: warning treated as error - no 'object' file generated**
The same project will get compiled in VS2003 and executing well.What I can do???

Thanks in advance

Comment: When u open the 2003 project in VS2005 it will prompt for u to convert the project to VS2005 so what do u need?

Comment: But even though i did the same thing when trying to compile project it shows errors such that object reference not found

Comment: Please update your post with the warnings preceeding that error.

Answer (score 0):

try to create a new 2005 solution and add the header and source files and compile. If you so you can see if the errors occur on the code or the project itself.

Answer (score 0):

Try providing a little detail in your questions, and you'll get more detail in the answers.

Is this an ASP.NET project? Are you running VS2005 SP1?

Make sure that VS hasn't created a Web Site "project" for you. They introduced this nonsense in VS2005, then re-added Web Application Projects in SP1. Make sure you're running SP1.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you have converted one or more C++ projects. The VS2005 compiler is more strict than the VS2003 one; you're suddenly getting warnings in a project that compiled fine with VS2003. You just have to fix the warnings, then you'll be fine. If you add the warning text to your question I can probably tell you how to fix it.

Regards,

Sebastiaan